# Resizing VirtualBox's disk size

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

I have a VM (VirtualBox) and its disk partitions are set up like this:

```
$ df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            979M     0  979M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M   24M  177M  12% /run
/dev/sda1       7.8G  6.9G  445M  95% /
tmpfs          1000M  216K 1000M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           200M   52K  200M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0         58M   58M     0 100% /media/ldl/VBox_GAs_5.2.0
```

I used `VBoxManage` to resize the VM's `.vdi` file

```
VBoxManage modifyhd "/Users/sof/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu14.04_01/ubuntu14.04_01.vdi" --resize 51200
```

and restarted the VM. Unfortunately this not work.

How do I resize the VM's drive?

---

**EDIT-01**

The guest OS is `Ubuntu 14.04`, and I want to extend its disk. but I don't know how to extend the partitions size.

Comment: `modifyhd` only resizes the hard disk size. It doesn't resize the partitions inside the drive. You need to resize those also

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three separate entities at play.

Initially your disk would have looked like this:

[image: disk layout #1]

### 1. Resize the Disk

By issuing the `modifyhd` command, you will have extended the disk:

[image: disk layout #2]

### 2. Resize the Partition

Now you need to modify the partition so that it uses the extra space.
You can use `fdisk` to do this.

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

- Take careful note of the partition's start and length using the print (`p`) command.
- Delete the partition (`d`)
- Create a new partition (`n`)

  - Use **the same *first sector*** as the old partition (now deleted)
  - Either use the default *last sector* or give another value - just make sure that the new partition is larger than it was previously
- Write the changes to disk (`w`)

You may need to use `partprobe` to force the kernel to re-read the partition tables. Use `lsblk` to verify that the partition is now the size you expect it to be.

You have now resized the partition too:

[image: disk layout #2]

### 3. Resize the Filesystem

The last step is to resize the filesystem, which can be done using `resize2fs` if it is an ext2/3/4 filesystem (it probably is). If you provide no size, then the filesystem will be resized to *fill* the available space.

```
resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

This can be done while the filesystem is mounted.

And at last, the filesystem has been resized too:

[image: disk layout #3]

You can verify this using `df` as before.